# Facebook Graph API - Service temporarily unavailable OAuthException

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am attempting to scrape the statuses of a public facebook place via version 2.11's posts endpoint. The generated URL I am calling is as follows:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/41585566807/posts?access_token=XXX&fields=message%2Clink%2Ccreated_time%2Ctype%2Cname%2Cid%2Ccomments.limit%280%29.summary%28true%29%2Cshares%2Creactions.limit%280%29.summary%28true%29&limit=100&after=Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5QTBNVFU0TlRVMk5qZA3dOem90TmprM05qWTFOREEwTmprMU1qUTVOREEwTXc4TVlYQnBYM04wYjNKNVgybGtEeDAwTVRVNE5UVTJOamd3TjE4eE1ERTFNRFF6TmpjME5UZAzNOamd3T0E4RWRHbHRaUVpPcUpBRUFRPT0ZD
```

I am paging through chunks of 100 statuses to return them all. This method works great for the first 2600 statuses on the page, but once I try to get the next 100, I get the following error message.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#2) Service temporarily unavailable",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "is_transient": true,
      "code": 2,
      "fbtrace_id": "EezWeUvcCXd"
   }
}
```

Even though, is_transient is true, it lasts through hours of repeated calls (every 5 seconds) to the api. Any idea why this error message is occurring and how to avoid it?

Comment: Hi, did you find out the solution for this problem?

Comment: No :/ I just added error handling to catch and ignore that error message after seeing it 3 times in a row. Let me know if you come across a better solution!

Comment: Sad to hear that. I'm finding the solution too :D